# Trying a Hybrid Sort Algorithm (Bubble + Merge Sort) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort, bubble-sort

So, I was tasked to create a hybrid sort function in python that would utilize bubble and merge sorts. The idea is simple; as long as the value T (threshold) is exceeded, merge sort should run recursively, whereas when the value is less than or equal to T, bubble sort is called. This slightly optimises the original merge sort function.

This is the code I've written:

```
def bubbleSort(arr, l, h):
    isSwapped = False
    size = h - l
    for i in range(size-1):
        for j in range(0, size-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                isSwapped = True
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
        if not isSwapped:
            return


def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    size1 = m - l + 1
    size2 = r - m

    l_arr = [0] * size1
    r_arr = [0] * size2

    for i in range(0, size1):
        l_arr[i] = arr[l + i]
    for j in range(0, size2):
        r_arr[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]

    # merge
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l

    while i < size1 and j < size2:
        if l_arr[i] <= r_arr[j]:
            arr[k] = l_arr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = r_arr[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < size1:
        arr[k] = l_arr[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < size2:
        arr[k] = r_arr[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1


def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if l < r:
        m = l + (r - l) // 2
        mergeSort(arr, l, m)
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r)
        merge(arr, l, m, r)
    else:
        return


def hybridMergeSort(arr, l, r):
    T = 16
    while l < r:
        if len(arr) <= T:
            bubbleSort(arr, l, r)
            break
        else:
            m = len(arr) // 2
            hybridMergeSort(arr, l, m)
            hybridMergeSort(arr, m + 1, r)
            merge(arr, l, m, r)
```

Similar logic worked for a hybrid quick-sort algorithm. I can't figure out what the issue is. It always returns an error: **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.** The same error is not returned when the mergeSort() function itself is used. I'm trying to use them for a random array of length 1000 by-the-way. I feel like the number of recursions should be the same?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are expected to show a [mre] and the full error meesage you get with it. In this case, python will tell you that the recursive call that hits the recursion limit is `hybridMergeSort(arr, l, m)`. This allows spotting the (edit: or at least one) error: `l` is not changed, and `m = len(arr) // 2` is not changed, so the next recursive call will be with the exact same arguments as the current recursive call, so the recursion will never stop.

Comment: @He3lixxx my apologies for the incomplete information. I figured out why the recursion error was showing up, and fixed it, but the issue is that now the function simply does not sort an array correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: Update the question so that it shows your fixes. `len(arr)` should be `(r - l + 1)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

In `bubbleSort`:

- you use the wrong index in the inner loop: you should shift the index range by `l`.
- you should reset `isSwapped` to `False` before the inner loop to stop the outer loop as soon as possible.
- since `l` and `h` are both included, the number of elements in the slice is `h - l + 1`, so the ranges are off by one.

  ```
  def bubbleSort(arr, l, h):
      for i in range(h - l):
          isSwapped = False
          for j in range(l, h-i-1):
              if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                 isSwapped = True
                 arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
          if not isSwapped:
             return
  ```

in `hybridMerge`:

- `while l < r:` is incorrect: it is causing an infinite loop as neither `l` nor `r` are modified inside the loop body.  Just write

  ```
    if l < r:
  ```
- testing `if len(arr) <= T` is incorrect: you should test if the length of the slice is smaller or equal to `T`,ie: if `h - l` is less than `T`:

  ```
    if r - l < T
  ```
- similarly, the mid point `m` must be computed from `h` and `l`, not from the length of the array.  This is the cause of the infinite recursion.

  ```
    m = l + (r - l) // 2
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
def bubbleSort(arr, l, h):
    for i in range(h - l):
        isSwapped = False
        for j in range(l, h-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                isSwapped = True
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            if not isSwapped:
                return

def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    size1 = m - l + 1
    size2 = r - m

    l_arr = arr[l : m+1]
    r_arr = arr[m+1 : r]

    # merge
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l

    while i < size1 and j < size2:
        if l_arr[i] <= r_arr[j]:
            arr[k] = l_arr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = r_arr[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < size1:
        arr[k] = l_arr[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < size2:
        arr[k] = r_arr[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1


def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if l < r:
        m = l + (r - l) // 2
        mergeSort(arr, l, m)
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r)
        merge(arr, l, m, r)
    else:
        return


def hybridMergeSort(arr, l, r):
    T = 16
    if r - l < T:
        if l < r:
            bubbleSort(arr, l, r)
    else:
        m = l + (r - l) // 2
        hybridMergeSort(arr, l, m)
        hybridMergeSort(arr, m + 1, r)
        merge(arr, l, m, r)
```